# Polynomial solutions of equation $P(t) - T_n(x)$ with Chebycheff polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Suppose we have, for fixed $P(t) \in \mathbb{Z}[t]$, infinite couples of integer solutions $(t_i, x_i) \in \mathbb{Z}$ to the equation
$$ P(t) - T_n(x) = 0 $$
where $T_n$ is the $n$-th [Chebycheff polynomial of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Definition) with $n$ a fixed **odd** integer.

Is it possible to conclude that there is a polynomial solution $A(t)$ such that $P(t) - T_n(A(t))$ is the zero polynomial or that there is a polynomial $B(x)$ such that $P(B(x)) - T_n(x) = 0$?

Edit: the answer to this question is NO (See joro answer: https://mathoverflow.net/q/280037).

Please focus only on the following one:

At least, is it possible to conclude that for each $t \in \mathbb{Z}$ except a finite set there is a solution $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that said equation holds?

Comment: There's no "Chebycheff", either using English or French transcription. In English it's Ch...sh... and in French Tch...ch..., even if most French people mispronounce the third consonant with an additional "t". English spelling is Chebyshev; in French Tchebychev or Tchebychef(f) (there are a few other alternatives, but definitely not with Ch...ch).

Answer (score 2):

Edit for the new question.

The answer is no.

Let $P(t)=T_m(t)$ for natural $m$. Integer parametrization of $P(t)=T_n(x)$ is $t=T_n(s),x=T_m(s)$ which is not of the wanted form.

---

Chebyshev polynomials satisfy $T_{nm}(x)=T_n(T_m(x))$ so setting $n=n'm$ and $P(t)=T_m(t)$ leads to $T_m(t)=T_{n'm}(x)$ which have the solution $t=T_{n'}(t),x=t$

Comment: Maybe I have misstated the question, but both $P(t)$ and $n$ are fixed beforehand.

As I understand your answer, you are setting $P(t) = T_{nm}(y)$ and $x = T_m(y)$. This is not the point of the question: I'm supposing there is a 
fixed $P(t)$ such that the curve $P(t) - T_n(x)$ has infinitely many integral points.

Comment: @trenta3 Isn't this the same as the answer? My curve has infinitely many integral points and P(t),n are fixed beforehand?

Comment: @trenta I had typo, A(t) instead of P(t), just edited.

Comment: Yes your curve has infinitely many integral points but you are choosing a $P(t)$. I'm not asking for an example where the statement holds.

Just to clarify i'm asking for the implication: There exists infinitely many integral solutions to $P(t) - T_n(x) = 0$ implies $\exists A(t)$ such that $P(t) = T_n(A(t))$ as polynomial.

Comment: @trenta3 In my example what is A(t) for the chosen P(t) ?

Comment: Sorry, I got confused by all $n$ and $m$'s. Reading your answer more carefully I can see that in your case we do not have $A(t)$ but instead we have a parametrization $t = B(x)$ that, when substituted, gives $P(B(x)) - T_n(x) = 0$.

I did not take this into account. I'll modify the question to also consider this case. Thank you very much.

Comment: @trenta3 ok. Have in mind it is possible P(a(t))=T_n(b(t)) and the curve must have rational parametrization.

Comment: @trenta3 I edited for the new question.

Comment: Ok, you are definitely right. I think I will just leave the second part of the question (and marking the first as solved negatively by you).

Answer (score 2):

There are quite general results on when a polynomial $F(x,y)\in\mathbb Z[x,y]$ has the property that $F(x,y)=0$ has infinitely many solutions in $\mathbb Z^2$. Roughly speaking, this happens if the affine variety $F=0$ contains the image of $\mathbb A^1$ or contains the image of $\mathbb G_m$. The former case gives a  solution in polynomials, the latter does not. See for example:

*Poulakis, Dimitrios*, [**Affine curves with infinitely many integral points**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-02-06841-7), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 131, No. 5, 1357-1359 (2003).

The criterion in that article may well let you solve your problem.